# Sets in STL of C++

Tags: c++11, stl, set

I have been reading about set container from cplusplus.com,
But I didn't understood what does the following line mean by ' direct iteration on subsets based on their order ' ?

***Set containers are generally slower than unordered_set containers to access individual elements by their key, but they allow the direct iteration on subsets based on their order.***

Comment: `std::set` is sorted, `std::unordered_set` is not. If you had a set of ints and wanted to do something to all of them with a value from N1 to N2 you can easily search and then iterate over them. To do the same with an unordered_set you would need to iterate over every item.

Comment: ok thanks Retired Ninja.